# Jquery cannot validate enabled form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am doing a complex registration form. I am doing a lot of Jquery.validation and works perfectly except at one form element. That form element is input=text. It is disabled at the begining and gets enabled if one of the radiobutton is selected. So, my validation system works as expected except on this input.

here is the html code...

```
    <form class="form_third">
      <div id="div_muayenehane" style="display:none">
         <div>Telefon&nbsp;<span id="Span13" style="font-size:11px;color:red"></div><div style="line-height: 3px">&nbsp;</div>
         <div><input type="text" id="txt_telefon" name="txt_telefon" style="width: 200px" class="blue_input required" minlength="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="02125556677"; /></div><div style="line-height: 6px">&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

here is the jquery code...

```
$("#form_third").validate({
            submitHandler: function () {
                return false;
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().prev().prev().children('span'));
            },
            rules: {
                txt_telefon: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                }
            }
        });
```

it should validate the txt_telefon and display the error message in Span13, but it doesnt work. It doesnt do anything. Do you think I should use ".on" event or something else because the div_muayenehane is disabled on load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$("#form_third")
```

It should be

```
$(".form_third")
```

since "form_third" is the class attribute, not the id.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. i will mark it as answered in 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

bit change in your form tag `<form id="form_third" class="form_third">`

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$("#form_third")


to


$(".form_third")
```

you need to use .(dot) for classes and # for Id.